# i have an error in recursive php function

Tags: php

```
    public function trovafigli($utenti, $figli) {
        if (array_keys($figli)[0]==00)
            {return null;}
        foreach ($utenti as $k => $utente) { 
            if (in_array($utente->nodo_superiore, array_keys($figli))) {
                $figli[$utente->alberoid] = $utente->user_id;
                unset($utenti[$k]);
                $this->trovafigli($utenti, $figli);
                }
            }     
        //die('debug  '.print_r($figli));
        return $figli;
    }
```

In this function if i leave debug uncomment i have result in 2 seconds with my array right, but if i comment my die debug i have"maximum execution time exceeded". why its happen and how can i solve ? thk u all

Comment: It depends where you are writing this code. Is it for a live server? I would probably find another solution.

Comment: i'm writing this code in a hosting linux and in a test xamp serve in my computer

Comment: `die()` aborts the script. You invoke it as soon as the first internal call to `trovafigli()` completes.

Comment: David marchesi thank you for the environment info! @ÁlvaroGonzález I did not know that about die as I am not a php developer but that is good to know! What do you think about recursion in a linux server. I would tend to stay away from recursive functions on a server in most places nowadays with all the reactive or naturally asynchronous code. It can be useful in certain cases. In the meantime as much time and effort as you spent on the function I would tend try to think of an iterative way... Or get some testing benchmarks with massive input

Comment: alvaro i call aborts when the recursive function is end i call just before return.....